# Android Edittext shift text instead of newline effect when inserting more text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to change the default effect of edittext when it doesn't have enough space to add more text.

[image]

but in my case I have defined fixed height and width to the edittext. Therefore it disappears the previous text when inserting more text.

[image]

Since this is inconvenient to the users, it is better if I can change this effect to shift text like this.

[image]

this is how I add an edittext

[image]

Please enlight me if you know how get this done. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting **inputType** on `EditText` like

```
 child.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
```